# How to grep to resolve "error: unknown type name 'boolean'"

Tags: c

I am trying to use the Android [NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) to compile a project and am getting the following error...

> error: unknown type name 'boolean'

I am assuming I am missing a header or some such that describes boolean. However, I can't seem to find it. Is there an easy way to grep for this?

Comment: You may want to rethink your tags. 'C' doesn't know boolean (or bool for that matter). Android is Java. Definitely not 'C'.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium The Android NDK it the "Native Development Kit", i.e. an SDK for native development in C or C++. Though It seems the OP is trying to compile a Java program with the C compiler.

Comment: Can you please provide more information? What does the code look like? How do you try to compile it?

Comment: @RefugnicEternium: C99 has a built-in type `_Bool` and the header `<stdbool.h>` exposes macros `bool`, `true`, `false` (and `__bool_true_false_are_defined`).

Comment: Yeah, I get it, I get it. Sorry, it seems I've been working with C90 and C++ too much. Though it's still interesting to learn about all this.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for me:

```
grep -r "typedef boolean" ./
```

Comment: That finds types that are defined as equivalent to `boolean`; it doesn't find uses of `boolean` as a type in general.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Got a better solution? I haven't accepted it yet?

Comment: If you've got GNU `grep`, then `grep -rw boolean .` will search for the word `boolean` in all files under the current directory.  One of those references is presumably your troublemaker; possibly several of them.  This answer is close; it could be fixed easily.  If you don't have GNU `grep`, drop the `w` from the options.  It matches words, but without it, most other versions of `grep` will work fine, but might pick up longer words too (such as `boolean_variable`) which `-w` would not.